# Using a nested for loop to find duplicates

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, arraylist, duplicates

I've been trying to write this code for a while now and I cannot figure out what is wrong with my nested for loop. I think it may be a problem with my if statement but I'm not sure. The code is supposed to search through ten random playing cards to find any duplicates. I know the rest of the code is working but I cannot figure out what I've done wrong with this part. If anyone could help I would be really grateful.  (Java)

```
    /*
 * Return true if there is a duplicate card in the pack
 */
public boolean hasDuplicate() {
    for (int i = 0; i < pack.size(); i++){
        for (int j = i; j < pack.size(); j++) {
            if (i != j && pack.get(i).equals(pack.get(j))){
                pos = i;
                return true;
            } 
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Seems like ok to me. How exactly is it not working? What is `pack`?

Comment: Did you override `.equals()` on whatever's in the list?

Comment: @RohitJain, pack is the arraylist that it is searching through. It is not working as in when I test it, the answer always comes out as false.

Comment: @Kevin.. How is that going to matter?

Comment: What does `pack.get(i)` return. I mean what is the type stored in the `List`?

Comment: You should post more of your code.

Comment: @RohitJain if he didn't override the equals method of whatever's in the ArrayList, then two equivalent objects may test as different and provide a false negative, as is happening here.

Comment: @Kevin.. That behaviour would happen only if OP override either `equals` or `hashCode` but not both.

Comment: @Srinivas, pos is a field to display the found duplicate.

Comment: @user2001375. Also note that, you can avoid `i != j ` test, by initializing `j = i + 1`, instead of `j = i`, in inner loop.

Comment: the nested For loop seems ok with me , so i think your error not from this code , try to post more of your code

Comment: The list is storing type Card, which is made up of the value of a playing card and the playing card's suit.

Comment: I bet you not override equals in `Card`

Comment: @RohitJain No, `x.equals(y)` by default returns `x == y`, i.e. identical equality. Nothing here has anything to do with hash.

Comment: This is the only code I have changed since I tested it. I'm fairly certain there is a problem with my if statement or something. /*
  * Return true if there is a duplicate card in the pack
  */
 public boolean hasDuplicate() {
  for (int i = 0; i < pack.size(); i++){
   for (int j = i; j < pack.size(); j++) {
    if (i != j && pack.get(i).equals(pack.get(j))){
     pos = i;
     return true;
    } 
   }
  }
  return false;
 }

 /*
  * Return any duplicate card, 'null otherwise
  */ 
 public Card getDuplicate() {
  if (this.hasDuplicate())
   return pack.get(pos);
  else 
   return null;
 }

}

Comment: @Kevin.. Ah! Holy Crap. I totally took that value as `String`, and skrewed the discussion. Sorry. In that case yes, OP needs to override `equals` and also `hashCode` .

Comment: Okay, so how I can fix that then. I don't know where I would have done that as I have used .equals elsewhere in my code with reference to the type Card but that still works.

Comment: Tangential suggestion: you could copy all the items in the array into a `Set<Card>`. If the size of the set is less than the size of the array, there was a duplicate. This incurs a bit of memory overhead but seems like a much clearer solution.

Comment: You could also improve the performance of your current approach by giving the cards a natural order and sorting the pack. There's a duplicate if for any `i` (in the appropriate bounds), `pack.get(i).equals(pack.get(i+1))`.

Answer (score 1):

The class you are using (`Card`) does not have an appropriately overridden `.equals()` method, so it is using the `Object` default - the equality operator (`==`) - to check whether two objects are equal. You are populating the array with a `new` object for each item in the array, so none of them are equal by `==`, and therefore none of them are `.equals()`. You need to override its `.equals()` method to return whether the cards are semantically equal (i.e. same rank and suit). While you're at it, you should override `hashCode` as well, to maintain the general contract (if `x.equals(y)` then `x.hashCode() == y.hashCode`).

Comment: Change the last line to: - `You must also override hashCode method` to maintain the contract between `equals` and `hashCode`.